# Advanced QoS on prioritized first packages set by ISP

Tags: ip, iptables, openwrt, qos

I have the following problem my ISP (Fibertel from Argentina) accelerates, 'enhances' the first 6.8 megabytes of downstream transfer and it's seems the first 1.8 megabytes of upstream transfer.

This makes very difficult for me to set a concise and proper QoS for my network.

When I enable QoS on my linux based router solution (openwrt). I lose this benefit since I don't know how to prioritize this first packages from my ISP.

I have a way to set 'number of bytes' on the luci GUI on the router, but I can't seem to make it work for this advanced behavior.

The connection I'm paying for is 6144 kilobits downstream 768 upstream. And the marketing name of this behavior is 'Fibertel Nitro'.

I really appreciate any help, I never heard of another ISP doing this kind of QoS for their users.